# Downsides of using convex layers for listing and counting points inside a triangle

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry

Given a set of points S and a triangle, what are the various reasons for which constructing and using the [convex layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers) of S is not optimal for counting and listing the points inside the triangle?

Comment: There are at least 2 reasons; try to come up with one yourself.

Comment: @j_random_hacker with a triangulation, the query time would be O(log n), whereas with the convex layers it would be O(n log n), if I got the math right.